# Turn inputs into objects in an array with a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, loops

how do I turn this

```
 <input class="optionsGraph" name="name1" value="value1">
 <input class="optionsGraph" name="name2" value="value2">
 <input class="optionsGraph" name="name3" value="value3">
 <input class="optionsGraph" name="name4" value="value4">
 <input class="optionsGraph" name="name5" value="value5">
```

into this (with a loop)?

```
var example = [
            { label: "name1",  y: value1, x: 1  },
            { label: "name2", y: value2, x: 2  },
            { label: "name3", y: value3, x: 3  },
            { label: "name4",  y: value4, x: 4  },
            { label: "name5",  y: value5, x: 5  }
          ];
```

I was thinking with something like this?

```
$(".optionsGraph").each(function(key) {
           //another loop

          });
```

I'm really struggling with this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) along with `.get()`

> As the return value is a jQuery object, which contains an array, it's very common to call `.get()` on the result to work with a basic array.

```js
var arr = $('.optionsGraph').map(function(index) {
  return {
    label: $(this).attr('name'), //Get attribute
    y: $(this).val(), //Get elements value
    x: index + 1
  }
}).get();

console.log(arr)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="optionsGraph" name="name1" value="value1">
<input class="optionsGraph" name="name2" value="value2">
<input class="optionsGraph" name="name3" value="value3">
<input class="optionsGraph" name="name4" value="value4">
<input class="optionsGraph" name="name5" value="value5">
```

Comment: What does `.get()` do here?

Comment: `map()` returns jQuery object, to get basic array you need `.get()` @DigiFriend

Answer (score 1):

Adding a line to your loop.

```
var output =[];
$(".optionsGraph").each(function(key) {
    output.push({label : $(this).attr("name"), y: $(this).val(), x : key+1 );
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/La25kkqz/

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
var res = [], i = 0;
$(".optionsGraph").each(function(key) {
           //another loop
        res.push({
        label: $(this).attr('name'),
      y : $(this).val(),
      x: ++i
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8qqphkpf/

Answer (score 0):

Pure js solution, using `Array#map`.

```js
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('optionsGraph'),
    res = Array.from(elems).map((v,i) => ({label: v.name, y: v.value, x: i+1}));
    
    console.log(res);
```

```html
<input class="optionsGraph" name="name1" value="value1">
<input class="optionsGraph" name="name2" value="value2">
<input class="optionsGraph" name="name3" value="value3">
<input class="optionsGraph" name="name4" value="value4">
<input class="optionsGraph" name="name5" value="value5">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this [`Array#push`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj7y_ai8uLTAhXIL48KHVaeCboQFgglMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2Fpush&usg=AFQjCNF2yVwy6jYb4it4O8eymeLbYX1akw)

```js
var example=[]
$(".optionsGraph").each(function(a,b) {
example.push({label:$(this).attr('name'),  y:$(this).val(), x: a+1})
 });
 console.log(example)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="optionsGraph" name="name1" value="value1">
 <input class="optionsGraph" name="name2" value="value2">
 <input class="optionsGraph" name="name3" value="value3">
 <input class="optionsGraph" name="name4" value="value4">
 <input class="optionsGraph" name="name5" value="value5">
```